# Why does JavaScript automatically sort the number keys in an object? How can I get around it? It messes up the index order that is important to me

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

let arr = [10,23,45,64,69,12,446,565,75,456];

let obj = {};

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i]
}

let values = Object.values(obj)
```

console.log(values)

i was expection values array to be:- [10, 23, 45, 64, 69, 12, 446, 565, 75, 456]

But I am Getting sorted values :- [
10, 12,  23,  45,  64,
69, 75, 446, 456, 565
]

Comment: because Objects properties have a defined order - especially when it comes to numerical keys - if you do `obj[\`_${arr[i]}\`] = arr[i]` you'll see that now, the order is the order the properties were created see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/5053002 or https://dev.to/frehner/the-order-of-js-object-keys-458d

Comment: In case you miss it, the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3702797) in the linked Q/A also contains the answer to "How can I get around it": use a `Map`. But in your case since what you apparently wanted was to remove the duplicate values from your Array, a `Set` as in the posted answer would indeed be more appropriate.